# OOP Inheritance eval(repr()) undesired outcome

Tags: python, oop

I created a class that inherits from the class list:

```
class Queue2(list):
    'a queue class, subclass of list'

    def isEmpty(self):
        'returns True if queue is empty, False otherwise'
        return (len(self)==0)

    def dequeue(self):
        'remove and return item at front of queue'
        return self.pop(0)

    def enqueue(self, item):
        'insert item at rear of queue'
        return self.append(item)
```

When I try to run eval(repr()), an AttributeError occurred:

```
>>> queue2 = Queue2(['a','b','c'])
>>> duplicate = eval(repr(queue2))
>>> duplicate
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> duplicate.enqueue('d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'enqueue'
```

I realized the repr(queue2) changes the Queue2 objects to a str, and the eval() method makes it a list.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Edit1:
Here are my attempts:
1.  I tried to override repr function:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self

def __eval__(self):
    return self
```

result:

```
>>> queue2 = Queue2(['a','b','c'])
>>> duplicate = eval(repr(queue2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type Queue2)
```

2. I tried to include str in the inheritance:

```
class Queue2(list,str):
    'a queue class, subclass of list'

    def isEmpty(self):
        'returns True if queue is empty, False otherwise'
        return (len(self)==0)

    def dequeue(self):
        'remove and return item at front of queue'
        return self.pop(0)

    def enqueue(self, item):
        'insert item at rear of queue'
        return self.append(item)

    def __eval__(self):
        return Queue2(self)
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ch8.py", line 168, in <module>
class Queue2(list,str):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Comment: Your class object s inheriting `list.__repr__` so of course it makes a list. You probably shouldn't be doing this anyway.

Comment: If you don't like the way `repr` behaves, then override its behavior. That's the primary tenet of OOP.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I tried, but this occured:"TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string"

Comment: `repr` returns a *string representation* so it has to return a string. If you include your attempted override in the question, perhaps we can help you with that.

Comment: ... yes. It must return string. What are you trying to return instead and why? What are you even trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @abccd This is a exercise problem in a intro Python book. It asks me to  'Explain what happened and offer a solution'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own `__repr__` that returns a string that will build a new instance of your class when you `eval` it. There's no `__eval__` special method, so trying to do stuff with that isn't accomplishing anything.

Here's a reasonable `__repr__` implementation that should work for you:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, super().__repr__())
```

This will produce a string that looks like: `"Queue2(['a', 'b', 'c'])"`. When that gets `eval`ed, it will produce a new instance of `Queue2`, rather than a list, which is what you want.

Note that while having a `__repr__` that can be passed to `eval` is nice, it's not a requirement. Sometimes you'll have a class that isn't designed to allow you to recreate it in one step (for instance, maybe your constructor only creates empty queues, never ones with stuff already in them). In that case, one convention is to use angled brackets around some text with the information contained in the class (e.g. `"<Queue2 contents: ['a', 'b', 'c']>"`). Lots of standard Python objects have reprs like this (such as function objects).

Comment: And such as `multiprocessing.Queue()`: `<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x10f850d90>`

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to define the `__repr__` that returns the class `Queue2` being initiated with the list:

```
class Queue2(list):
    'a queue class, subclass of list'

    def isEmpty(self):
        'returns True if queue is empty, False otherwise'
        return (len(self)==0)

    def dequeue(self):
        'remove and return item at front of queue'
        return self.pop(0)

    def enqueue(self, item):
        'insert item at rear of queue'
        return self.append(item)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Queue2({})".format(super().__repr__())


queue2 = Queue2(['a','b','c'])
duplicate = eval(repr(queue2))
print(duplicate)
duplicate.enqueue('d')
print(duplicate)

# Queue2(['a', 'b', 'c'])
# Queue2(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```